# Access C++ backend from QML registered type

Tags: c++, qt, qml

On Qt5, I created my own class to draw a custom graphic with ellipse on it (please don't pay attention to this "simple" example, it is just a repoductible example, my code is far more complex) :

ellipseitem.h

```
#ifndef ELLIPSEITEM_H
#define ELLIPSEITEM_H

#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QTimer>

class EllipseItem : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)

public:
    explicit EllipseItem(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr);
    void paint(QPainter *painter) override;

    QColor color() const;
    void setColor(const QColor &newColor);
    void getData();

signals:
    void colorChanged();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;

    void handleTimer();

private:
    QColor m_color;
    QTimer *timer;
    bool m_isRunning = false;
};

#endif
```

ellipseitem.cpp

```
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTimer>
#include "ellipseitem.h"

static QColor randomColor()
{
    return QColor(qrand() & 0xff, qrand() & 0xff, qrand() & 0xff);
}

EllipseItem::EllipseItem(QQuickItem *parent)
    : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
    // This is necessary, by default QQuickItem does not accept any buttons
    setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);

    timer = new QTimer();

    QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &EllipseItem::handleTimer);
}

void EllipseItem::handleTimer()
{
    if (m_isRunning)
        setColor(randomColor());
}

void EllipseItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    painter->save();
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->setBrush(m_color);
    painter->drawEllipse(contentsBoundingRect());
    painter->restore();
}

QColor EllipseItem::color() const
{
    return m_color;
}

void EllipseItem::setColor(const QColor &newColor)
{
    if (m_color != newColor) {
        m_color = newColor;
        update();
        emit colorChanged();
    }
}

void EllipseItem::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED( event )
    m_isRunning = !m_isRunning;
    if (m_isRunning)
        timer->start(1000);
    else
        timer->stop();
}
    
void EllipseItem::getData()
{
    // In some way, get data from the single instance of DataModelClass to use it here (for example I would like to call the getData method of DataModelClass instance)
}
```

I also have a backend in which I have a lot of class to manage data models, connection with a server, ..., such as:

datamodelclass.h

```
#ifndef DATAMODELCLASS_H
#define DATAMODELCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>

class DataModelClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DataModelClass() {}

    Q_INVOKABLE QVector<int> getData()
    {
        return m_data;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void apprendData( int newData)
    {
        m_data.append(newData);

        // Emit signal here to tell EllipseItem data has been updated
    }

    QVector<int> m_data = {};
};

#endif // DATAMODELCLASS_H
```

In the `main.cpp`, I am connecting the backend to the QML frontend through  `setContextProperty` with pointer of my data class. I also registered my custom graphic using `qmlRegisterType<EllipseItem>()`:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "ellipseitem.h"
#include "datamodelclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    DataModelClass *myClass = new DataModelClass();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("_myClass", myClass);
    qmlRegisterType<EllipseItem>("Shapes", 5, 0, "Ellipse");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

In this way, in my qml I can create instance of my custom graphic:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Shapes 5.0

Item {
    width: 300; height: 200

    // Create one instance of Ellipse
    Ellipse {
        width: parent.width/2; height: parent.height
        x:0
        y:0
        color: "blue"

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: parent.color
        }
    }

    // Create a second instance of Ellipse
    Ellipse {
        width: parent.width/2; height: parent.height
        x: parent.width/2
        y: 0
        color: "red"

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: parent.color
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do:

- When data is updated in the `DataModelClass`, emit a signal or something else to avert the instance of the `CustomGraphicItem` in the C++ new data are available
- From the `CustomGraphicItem` class, read data in the `DataModelClass` instance (but I have not a pointer to the `DataModelClass` to call the method getData in my example)
- Update with this new data the graphics through the paint method of my `CustomGraphicItem` class (my side)
- Tell the GUI a new graphic has to be displayed with the `update` signal (this is already done)

Maybe it is possible to do in other way.

Comment: TBH, I am unsure what you are asking; are you trying to attach an instance of `DataModelClass` to an instance of `CustomGraphicItem`? If that is it, even if you write a property binding in qml file (e.g. `dataModel: DataModelClass { [...] }`), everything happens in C++ (a `DataModelClass` gets instanciated, then the setter you defined for the `dataModel` property gets called with that instance) so there should be no need to become overly concerned with QML here. Please edit your question if I did not understand.

Comment: I updated the end of my post to clarify a little what I want. You have right, I want to access `DataModelClass` from `CustomGraphicItem`. But your solution involves to "create the instance" of the `DataModelClass` in the QML through the property. In my case, this instance is already existing because creating in the `QmlInterfaceSet` class which connect also this `DataModelClass` to other C++ classes.

Comment: Since you are using a subclass of `QAbstractItemModel`, normally use the `dataChanged` signal, and the `data` method to respectively detect when data changes and read it from your model. As for your comment that you have no pointer to `DataModelClass`, that should not be the case if you created a property. For me to answer, you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) though, like something that draws text at predefined coordinates from a `QStandardItemModel`

Comment: Don't hesitate to have a look to QML examples from Qt creator too.

Comment: Example added ;) I already look at a lot of documentation but I am confused because lot of things are possible on Qt :X

Comment: *"but I have not a pointer to the DataModelClass to call the method getData in my example"* -- Yes you do. You exposed your instance of DataModelClass with setContextProperty. So you can reference `_myClass` anywhere in your QML code.

Comment: There should be no direct link between the model, and an individual delegate, or the view for that matter. The model-view-delegate stuff is a bit convoluted, and IMO the documentation is not the best of Qt docs, so please play around with the examples to see how it is meant to be done. Even if you then do it your own way, you should know the default way first!

Comment: Is this an academic exercise in using QQuickPaintedItem in C++? Since, if this is a question about drawing Ellipse in QML, QML already has that capability.

Comment: @JarMan, yes I have the instance, but do you mean I have to give this reference to my Ellipse component through a property of the Ellipse component ? I will see if I can do something (maybe try to connect signal of DataModelClass with its reference and my EllipseItem class in this last one directly

Comment: @hyde, I already have a complex software with a lot of QML/C++ mechanisms (with property, q_invokable, whatever), I am just facing a new situation in my program. I try to do the right way instead of doing ugly code. It is why I am asking here some advice. There is so many examples it is difficult to find sometimes what we are looking for without help

Comment: @stephen, it is not an academic exercice, I have to draw a complex graph but for the example I just add an ellipse. I can't only use a Canvas component for performance issue, I have to refresh at 60Hz my graph and the Qt documentation tell to use this kind of thing. I already tried both solution and effectivily the Canvas solution is not the good one for my problematic.

Comment: Ellipses can be drawn declaratively with Shape, ShapePath and PathArc. No need for Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the help giving on comments (thanks to all), I finally find the "right" way to do it on my problem, using a Q_PROPERTY to give the pointer of the graphics class of my data class.

Here is my new code (the left ellipse is connected to the data, but clicking on the right ellipse make add a new data and send a signal which is connected to the left ellipse now)

ellipseItem.h

```
#ifndef ELLIPSEITEM_H
#define ELLIPSEITEM_H

#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QTimer>
#include "datamodelclass.h"

class EllipseItem : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(DataModelClass * dataModelClass WRITE setDataModelClass)

public:
    explicit EllipseItem(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr);
    void paint(QPainter *painter) override;

    QColor color() const;
    void setColor(const QColor &newColor);
    void getData();

signals:
    void colorChanged();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event) override;

    void handleTimer();

    // New code
    void setDataModelClass(DataModelClass* dataModelClass)
    {
        m_dataModelClass = dataModelClass;
        QObject::connect(m_dataModelClass, &DataModelClass::dataUpdated,
                         this, &EllipseItem::dataUpdated);
    }

    // New code
    void dataUpdated()
    {
        qDebug() << m_dataModelClass->getData();
    }

private:
    QColor m_color;
    QTimer *timer;
    bool m_isRunning = false;

    // New code
    DataModelClass * m_dataModelClass = nullptr;
};

#endif
```

ellipseItem.cpp = same file

main.cpp (small change to display an application window and use engine for the QML part too)

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "ellipseitem.h"
#include "datamodelclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    DataModelClass* myClass = new DataModelClass();

    // Create bindings between QML and C++ classes for QML panels
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("_myClass", myClass);
    qmlRegisterType<EllipseItem>("Shapes", 5, 0, "Ellipse");

    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

dataModelClass.h

```
#ifndef DATAMODELCLASS_H
#define DATAMODELCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>

class DataModelClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DataModelClass() {
        this->apprendData(2);
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QVector<int> getData()
    {
        return m_data;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void apprendData( int newData)
    {
        m_data.append(newData);

        // Emit signal here to tell EllipseItem data has been updated
        emit dataUpdated();    
    }

signals:
    void dataUpdated();

private:
    QVector<int> m_data = {};
};

#endif // DATAMODELCLASS_H
```

And finally the main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import Shapes 5.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300; height: 200
    visible: true

    // Create one instance of Ellipse
    Ellipse {
        width: parent.width/2; height: parent.height
        x:0
        y:0
        color: "blue"
        dataModelClass: _myClass

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: parent.color
        }
    }

    // Create a second instance of Ellipse
    Ellipse {
        width: parent.width/2; height: parent.height
        x: parent.width/2
        y: 0
        color: "red"

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: parent.color
        }

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent

            onClicked: _myClass.apprendData(Math.random()*100)
        }
    }
}
```